# Flash + javascript calls + crossdomain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain

I'm facing a problem with Flash,crossdomain and javascript calls.

I'm running a PHP project. In development, I'm not using any subdomain for images & swf files and everything is working fine.

In production server all my images & flash files are loaded from a subdomain like subdomain.domain.com. Javascript files are hosted in domain.com. At some point, the javascript file will load the swf file but this is not displayed. Apart from that, the swf file should call to javascript functions, but those are not executed (tested with firebug).

Why the javascript functions are not executed from the swf file? I think that the error is because the swf files are located in subdomains and javascript in a domain and there is no communication between them, but I dont know how to fix it. Can you give me some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with crossdomain.xml ?

Comment: i already checked this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179878/flash-and-cross-domain-problem] and tried locating that file in the root directory but I'm not getting the calls from the swf. I do those javascript calls from the swf file using the InternalInterface.call function.